# DatePicker custom template leaves a white box inside

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker

I am trying to make a custom template for datepickers in my program. I am basically using this template line for line (changing colors and things):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278067(v=vs.95).aspx

I have tried going through it and getting rid of this white box (**the one INSIDE the datepicker textbox)**, but it is evading me. Here is a screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image]

Do I have to add something extra? Or change some existing values? There is also a MouseOver event that highlights the whitebox with the blue windows gradient, if that helps..

For future people with this problem, I did what Brian suggested, just thought I would post exactly my code, so other people can use it ;) I just added this into app.xaml

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}" TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">        
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">

                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource cControlColor}" BorderThickness="1" 
                                Background="{DynamicResource cControlColor}"/>     
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Updating since the clarification points to the white rectangle around the 'Enter text here'.

For this, you need to create a custom template for the `DatePickerTextBox` which is defined about 2/3rds of the way down that template, and named TextBox.  Your best bet will be to use Blend to create a custom template (since it will generate the default template) and then modify the `<Border x:Name="watermark_decorator".../>` to change the `BorderBrush`.  For example:

```
<Style x:Key="MyDatePickerTextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
           <Grid>                 
           <!-- Visual State Manager stuff -->
             <Border...>
               <!-- other stuff... -->
               <Border x:Name="watermark_decorator" BorderBrush="[THE BRUSH YOU WANT]" BorderThickness="1">
                 <!-- And so on and so forth... -->
               </Border>
             </Border>
           </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then, in the `DatePicker` template, modify the DatePickerTextBox to use this style:

```
<!-- All DatePicker Template stuff -->
<controlsPrimitives:DatePickerTextBox x:Name="TextBox" Style="{DynamicResource MyDatePickerTextBoxStyle}" ... />
```

Are you talking about the button with the 15 on it?  If so, the look and feel of this part of the `DatePicker` is defined in the "DropDownButtonTemplate" part of the template.  This template includes a large `VisualStateManager` section, but then defines the template for that button.  There are comments that define the beginning and end of the button template:

```
<!--Start UI-->
... this is the Button Template ...
<!-- End UI-->
```

For example, if you want to change the color of the Blue rectangle at the top of the button, the MSDN example uses this:

```
<Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1">
  <Rectangle.Stroke>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.48,-1" StartPoint="0.48,1.25">
       <GradientStop Color="#FF494949" />
       <GradientStop Color="#FF9F9F9F" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Stroke>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.3,-1.1" StartPoint="0.46,1.6">
      <GradientStop Color="#FF4084BD" />
      <GradientStop Color="#FFAFCFEA" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

And you could change it to a solid color simply by changing it to this:

```
<Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Black" Fill="Green"/>
```

The "White Box" is actually the `Border` inside the template with the `x:Name="BackgroundGradient"`, so if you change the Background of that element, you can get rid of the white.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I am talking about the white rectangle INSIDE the datepicker ...textbox?

Comment: Ok, in that case, you need to customize the template of the `DatePickerTextBox` control, and specifically, the `<Border x:Name="watermark_decorator"...` element inside that template.  I'll post another answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: Yay!!! GOT IT FIGURED OUT! Thanks sooo much for the help man! Couldnt have done it without you

Comment: Hi Toadmus, how did you fixed it. I am having the same issue and cant figure it out